# I can't install the unity localization plugin

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I try to install the localization plugin from git, the plugin loads but I get the following errors. my unity version is 2020.1.0f1. how can i solve this?

> Library\PackageCache\com.unity.addressables@1.20.5\Runtime\AssetReference.cs(924,27): error CS0117: 'AssetDatabase' does not contain a definition for 'SaveAssetIfDirty'

> Library\PackageCache\com.unity.addressables@1.20.5\Runtime\AssetReference.cs(924,58): error CS0117: 'AssetDatabase' does not contain a definition for 'GUIDFromAssetPath'

https://ibb.co/GPysxp0
https://ibb.co/CQMDRHP

Answer (score 0):

AssetDatabase.SaveAssetIfDirty does not exist in unity 2020.1 You need to upgrade to at least 2020.3 [image: as you can see in the documentation]

Which is odd, because the unity localization package is supposed for version 2019.4 and above, according to this thread:
https://forum.unity.com/threads/release-announcements-and-notes.597262/#post-8519747